# How can I call the filename created?

Tags: java

I have call an image and cropped the region and also detected the characters.
This is the part where the characters in the image is cropped.

```
`if (rect.height > 25){
     Core.rectangle(result, rect.tl(), rect.br(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0));
     Imgproc.drawContours(cropped, contours, -1, new Scalar(255,0,0));

     System.out.println(rect.x +"-"+ rect.y +"-"+ rect.height+"-"+rect.width);
     Highgui.imwrite("2)Detected Box_" +a+".jpg",result);

     for(int k=0; k < 8;k++){
            Mat crop1 = new Mat(result,rect);
            Imgproc.floodFill(result, croppedM, shift, new Scalar(0,0,250));
            Mat invertFill = new Mat();
            //Core.bitwise_not(crop1, invertFill);

            try{
                Highgui.imwrite("charCrop"+a+"_"+i+".jpg",crop1);
                System.out.println(template_img);
                //String e = crop1[k].toString();
                Mat  image_ = Highgui.imread("charCrop"+a+"_"+i+".jpg",Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
                Mat template = Highgui.imread(template_img,Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);`
```

This is part of my code where I write a new file of the cropped characters at `Highgui.imwrite("charCrop"+a+"_"+i+".jpg",crop1);`

My question is how can I call the created file at `Mat  image_ = Highgui.imread("charCrop"+a+"_"+i+".jpg",Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);` without calling directly the file name as this part will continue to call the next file image that have been created.